# me.control.remove is removing every second control in a loop for some reason

Tags: vb.net

I have some dynamically created checkboxes on my form and I want a function to delete them all.

I've got the following function:

```
Sub delete_checkboxes()
        Dim radios = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).AsQueryable()
        For Each r As RadioButton In radios
            Me.Controls.Remove(r)
        Next
End Sub
```

For some reason the above function only deletes every second radio button and leaves the rest.

Just as a test, I changed the function to delete radio buttons which are ticked:

```
Dim radios = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).AsQueryable()
For Each r As RadioButton In radios
   If r.Checked Then
       Me.Controls.Remove(r)
   End If
Next
```

With the above I can tick each radio button and it will delete them invididually... so what it is in the first function which could be causing it to skip every second radio button?

Comment: because when you remove one (which happens before NEXT) everything moves down one (#6 becomes #5), so NEXT goes to #7.  Loop backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `AsQueryable()` to `ToList()`

The reason it fails is that you are not supposed to modify a iterator while you are still looping over it. `AsQueryable()` is just using a state machine internally to know your current position in the `Me.Controls` collection. It doesn't actually keep it's own collection of controls, but just knows which controls you need from your original collection.

When you remove a control in the middle of loop, that position state is now wrong... in fact, it's off by one. You then remove the next control, which puts that internal position state off by one again, and so on. After a whole set of off-by-one adjustments and you end up with half of the controls still on your form.

`ToList()` will work, because it creates a separate collection for your controls, so that you don't have to mess with that state as your remove them from your `Me.Controls` collection.

Comment: Thanks that was the quickest solution

Answer (score 1):

this is usually how I accomplish it.

```
    For Each cont As Control In Me.Controls
        If cont.GetType().Name = "RadioButton" Then Me.Controls.Remove(cont)
    Next
```

Comment: `AsQueryable()` returns an `IQueryable` object, which doesn't specify an indexer property... just an Enumerator and Expression tree.

Comment: Well changed my answer anyways. This is how I've done it in the past

Comment: But now you're modifying the collection as you iterate it again.